# In SQL, how do I rank the values within a ranked group?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to return the most common health issues and the hospital that has the highest count of that issue. So I was able to get it to return the most common issues in the US by grouping the issues. How do I get it to return the hospital within that issue that most commonly encounters it?

The table I'm querying looks like this:

```
provider_id | drg_definition | provider_name | total_discharges
1234        | 104 joint repl | Bost Regional | 4000
1235        | 105 hrt attack | NYC emergency | 7000
```

This is what I have:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  drg_definition,
  SUM(total_discharges) total_discharge_per_drg
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.hospital_general_info` gi
INNER JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.inpatient_charges_2015` ic
ON
  gi.provider_id = ic.provider_id
GROUP BY
 drg_definition
ORDER BY
  total_discharge_per_drg DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

My desired output is

```
Row | drg_definition | total_discharge_per_dsg | top_provider | cases
1   | 104 joint      | 15000                   | Austin       | 4000
```

*All numbers are made up, the columns and table format are not

Comment: It is not easy to retro-engineer the table structure starting from your query and explanation.You would need to provide us with sample data and expected results (this is a best practice for sql questions).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What do you mean by "deals with it the most"?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Just edited it to be more clear.

Comment: @oabdel: your query is pulling data from two tables, but you are showing only one in your sample data. And the results has columns that do not exist in the sample data (such as `top_city` and `cases`). This is still not helping enough. Keep in mind that we folks have no knowledge of your data structures...

Comment: You could use a corelated subquery for the `top_city` column that finds the most frequent hospital for the `drg_definition` in the row.

Comment: @GMB I made up top_city and cases

Comment: I haven't used the general info DB yet

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT drg_definition,
       SUM(total_discharges) as total_discharge_per_drg,
       ARRAY_AGG(ic.provider_id ORDER BY total discharges DESC LIMIT 1) as provider_with_most_discharges
FROM `bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.hospital_general_info` gi INNER JOIN
      `bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.inpatient_charges_2015` ic
      ON gi.provider_id = ic.provider_id
GROUP BY drg_definition
ORDER BY total_discharge_per_drg DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: YES! This is phenomenal, thank you. Two questions: How does this array's logic work? This returns the number of discharges the provider dealt with, but does not display the name. How can I add a column for the name of that provider? Below is the new output                                                                                                  Row | drg_definition | total_discharge_per_dsg | provider_with_most_discharges
1      | 104 joint         | 15000                               | 4000

Comment: @oabdel . . . Use `provider_name` if you want the name, rather than `provider_id`.  If you want to understand `array_agg()`, I would refer you to the BQ document.

Comment: [Doc regarding `array_agg()`](http://cloud/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg).